# Solving Poisson Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, poissons-equation

I have the following equation:

$$ 
\begin{cases}
  H_{xx} + H_{yy} = xy \\
  H(x,0) = 0 \\
  H(x,1) = x \\
  H(0,y) = 0 \\
  H(1,y) = 0
\end{cases}
$$

We want to solve this, so from inspection of eigenvalues and eigenfunctions we see the solution takes the form of: $ H(x,y) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \! Y_{n}(y)\sin(n\pi x) $.

Using *undertermined coefficients* we see:

$$
   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[ Y_{n}''-n^2\pi^2 Y_{n}(y) \right]\sin(n\pi x) = xy
$$

$$
   E_{n}(y) = 2\int_0^1 \! xy\sin(n\pi x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{2y\Bigl(-n\pi\cos(n\pi )+\sin(n\pi)\Bigr)}{n^2 \pi ^2} = -\frac{2(-1)^n y}{n\pi}
$$

Thus complementary solution being,

$$
   Y_{n}(y) = a_{n}\cosh(n\pi y) + b_{n}\sinh(n\pi y) + c + dy 
$$

$c=0,\quad d = \dfrac{2}{\pi^3}\dfrac{\cos(n\pi)}{n^3}$

Applying conditions:

$ H(x,0) = 0 = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}\sin(n\pi x),\hspace{0.2cm} 
  \rightarrow \hspace{0.1cm} a_{n}=0 
$

$ H(x,1) = x = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Bigl[ b_{n}\sinh(n\pi) + d \Bigr]   
  \sin(n\pi x) 
$

How would we continue from here to determine the $b_{n}$ coefficient? Is there a more elegant way to solve the non-homogeneous Poisson problem in general besides method of undetermined coefficients?

Comment: How do you square $H(1,y)=0$ with $H(x,1)=x$? What is $H(1,1)$?

Comment: @night owl not "to solve" the coefficient. Determine, calculate or so.

Answer (score 2):

Express $x$ is a Fourier sine series: if $x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n \sin(n \pi x)$, then $b_n = (c_n - d)/\sinh(n \pi)$.

Alternatively, you could start by looking for a particular solution, which isn't hard to find (hint: try one of the form $h(x) y$).  Then you need to solve Laplace's equation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H=K+Ax^3y+Axy^3$ ,

Then $H_x=K_x+3Ax^2y+Ay^3$

$H_{xx}=K_{xx}+6Axy$

$H_y=K_y+Ax^3+3Axy^2$

$H_{yy}=K_{yy}+6Axy$

$\therefore K_{xx}+6Axy+K_{yy}+6Axy=xy$

$K_{xx}+K_{yy}=(1-12A)xy$

$\therefore1-12A=0$

$A=\dfrac{1}{12}$

For $K_{xx}+K_{yy}=0$ , although it has a nice form of the general solution $K(x,y)=C_1(x+iy)+C_2(x-iy)$ , i.e. $H_{xx}+H_{yy}=xy$ has a nice form of the general solution $H(x,y)=C_1(x+iy)+C_2(x-iy)+\dfrac{xy(x^2+y^2)}{12}$ , it is difficult to directly substitute $H(x,0)=0$ , $H(x,1)=x$ , $H(0,y)=0$ and $H(1,y)=0$ to find $C_1(u)$ and $C_2(v)$ (at least I have no idea to these).

So it seems that we are unavoidable to solve these by using separation of variables.

For $K_{xx}+K_{yy}=0$ with conditions of the types $K(x,0)$ , $K(x,1)$ , $K(0,y)$ and $K(1,y)$ , according to http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/lpde/lpde301.pdf#page=2 , we have special consideration:

$K(x,y)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A(n)\sinh(n\pi(1-x))\sin n\pi y+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(n)\sinh n\pi x\sin n\pi y+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty C(n)\sin n\pi x\sinh(n\pi(1-y))+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sin n\pi x\sinh n\pi y$

$\therefore H(x,y)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A(n)\sinh(n\pi(1-x))\sin n\pi y+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(n)\sinh n\pi x\sin n\pi y+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty C(n)\sin n\pi x\sinh(n\pi(1-y))+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sin n\pi x\sinh n\pi y+\dfrac{xy(x^2+y^2)}{12}$

$H(x,0)=0$ :

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty C(n)\sin n\pi x\sinh n\pi=0$

$C(n)=0$

$\therefore H(x,y)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A(n)\sinh(n\pi(1-x))\sin n\pi y+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(n)\sinh n\pi x\sin n\pi y+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sin n\pi x\sinh n\pi y+\dfrac{xy(x^2+y^2)}{12}$

$H(0,y)=0$ :

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A(n)\sinh n\pi\sin n\pi y=0$

$A(n)=0$

$\therefore H(x,y)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(n)\sinh n\pi x\sin n\pi y+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sin n\pi x\sinh n\pi y+\dfrac{xy(x^2+y^2)}{12}$

$H(x,1)=x$ :

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sin n\pi x\sinh n\pi+\dfrac{x(x^2+1)}{12}=x$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sinh n\pi\sin n\pi x=\dfrac{x(11-x^2)}{12}$

You are facing to find an unusual kernel inversion, so all the calculations should be start from first principle!

Luckily the method in [fancy about inverse discrete Fourier sine and cosine transform (i.e. Fourier sine and cosine series)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183459) still hold in this case.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sinh n\pi\sin n\pi x=\dfrac{x(11-x^2)}{12}$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sinh n\pi\sin n\pi x\sin m\pi x=\dfrac{x(11-x^2)\sin m\pi x}{12}$

$\int_k^{k+1}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sinh n\pi\sin n\pi x\sin m\pi x~dx=\int_k^{k+1}\dfrac{x(11-x^2)\sin m\pi x}{12}dx$ , $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sinh n\pi\int_k^{k+1}\sin n\pi x\sin m\pi x~dx=\int_k^{k+1}\dfrac{x(11-x^2)\sin m\pi x}{12}dx$ , $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$

$\because\int_k^{k+1}\sin n\pi x\sin m\pi x~dx$

$=\int_{k}^{k+1}\dfrac{\cos((n-m)\pi x)-\cos((n+m)\pi x)}{2}dx$

$=\begin{cases}\biggl[\dfrac{\sin((n-m)\pi x)}{2(n-m)\pi}-\dfrac{\sin((n+m)\pi x)}{2(n+m)\pi}\biggr]_{k}^{k+1}&\text{when}~n\neq m~\text{and}~n\neq-m\\\biggl[\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{\sin((n+m)\pi x)}{2(n+m)\pi}\biggr]_{k}^{k+1}&\text{when}~n=m\\\biggl[\dfrac{\sin((n-m)\pi x)}{2(n-m)\pi}-\dfrac{x}{2}\biggr]_{k}^{k+1}&\text{when}~n=-m\\\left[0\right]_{k}^{k+1}&\text{when}~n=m~\text{and}~n=-m\end{cases}$

$=\begin{cases}0&\text{when}~n,m~\text{and}~k~\text{are integers and}~n\neq m~\text{and}~n\neq-m~\text{and}~(n=m~\text{and}~n=-m)\\\dfrac{1}{2}&\text{when}~n,m~\text{and}~k~\text{are integers and}~n=m\\-\dfrac{1}{2}&\text{when}~n,m~\text{and}~k~\text{are integers and}~n=-m\end{cases}$

$\therefore D(m)\sinh m\pi\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\int_k^{k+1}\dfrac{x(11-x^2)\sin m\pi x}{12}dx$ , $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$ , $x\in(k,k+1)$

$D(m)=\int_k^{k+1}\dfrac{x(11-x^2)\sin m\pi x}{6\sinh m\pi}dx$ , $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$ , $x\in(k,k+1)$

$D(n)=\int_k^{k+1}\dfrac{x(11-x^2)\sin n\pi x}{6\sinh n\pi}dx$ , $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$ , $x\in(k,k+1)$

According to http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=%28x%2811-x%5E2%29sin%28n+pi+x%29%29%2F%286sinh%28n+pi%29%29&random=false,

$D(n)=\int_k^{k+1}\dfrac{x(11-x^2)\sin n\pi x}{6\sinh n\pi}dx$

$=\dfrac{(-1)^{n(k+1)}(k+1)(n^2\pi^2((k+1)^2-11)-6)-(-1)^{nk}k(n^2\pi^2(k^2-11)-6)}{6n^3\pi^3\sinh n\pi}$ , $\forall n,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ , $x\in(k,k+1)$

$H(1,y)=0$ :

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(n)\sinh n\pi\sin n\pi y+\dfrac{y(y^2+1)}{12}=0$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(n)\sinh n\pi\sin n\pi y=-\dfrac{y(y^2+1)}{12}$

Note that you are facing to find an unusual kernel inversion again, so all the calculations should be again to start from first principle!

Luckily the method in [fancy about inverse discrete Fourier sine and cosine transform (i.e. Fourier sine and cosine series)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183459) still hold in this case.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(n)\sinh n\pi\sin n\pi y=-\dfrac{y(y^2+1)}{12}$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(n)\sinh n\pi\sin n\pi y\sin m\pi y=-\dfrac{y(y^2+1)\sin m\pi y}{12}$

$\int_k^{k+1}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(n)\sinh n\pi\sin n\pi y\sin m\pi y~dy=\int_k^{k+1}-\dfrac{y(y^2+1)\sin m\pi y}{12}dy$ , $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(n)\sinh n\pi\int_k^{k+1}\sin n\pi y\sin m\pi y~dy=\int_k^{k+1}-\dfrac{y(y^2+1)\sin m\pi y}{12}dy$ , $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$

$\because\int_k^{k+1}\sin n\pi y\sin m\pi y~dy$

$=\int_{k}^{k+1}\dfrac{\cos((n-m)\pi y)-\cos((n+m)\pi y)}{2}dy$

$=\begin{cases}\biggl[\dfrac{\sin((n-m)\pi y)}{2(n-m)\pi}-\dfrac{\sin((n+m)\pi y)}{2(n+m)\pi}\biggr]_{k}^{k+1}&\text{when}~n\neq m~\text{and}~n\neq-m\\\biggl[\dfrac{y}{2}-\dfrac{\sin((n+m)\pi y)}{2(n+m)\pi}\biggr]_{k}^{k+1}&\text{when}~n=m\\\biggl[\dfrac{\sin((n-m)\pi y)}{2(n-m)\pi}-\dfrac{y}{2}\biggr]_{k}^{k+1}&\text{when}~n=-m\\\left[0\right]_{k}^{k+1}&\text{when}~n=m~\text{and}~n=-m\end{cases}$

$=\begin{cases}0&\text{when}~n,m~\text{and}~k~\text{are integers and}~n\neq m~\text{and}~n\neq-m~\text{and}~(n=m~\text{and}~n=-m)\\\dfrac{1}{2}&\text{when}~n,m~\text{and}~k~\text{are integers and}~n=m\\-\dfrac{1}{2}&\text{when}~n,m~\text{and}~k~\text{are integers and}~n=-m\end{cases}$

$\therefore B(m)\sinh m\pi\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\int_k^{k+1}-\dfrac{y(y^2+1)\sin m\pi y}{12}dy$ , $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$ , $y\in(k,k+1)$

$B(m)=\int_k^{k+1}-\dfrac{y(y^2+1)\sin m\pi y}{6\sinh m\pi}dy$ , $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$ , $y\in(k,k+1)$

$B(n)=\int_k^{k+1}-\dfrac{y(y^2+1)\sin n\pi y}{6\sinh n\pi}dy$ , $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$ , $y\in(k,k+1)$

According to http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=-%28x%28x%5E2%2B1%29sin%28n+pi+x%29%29%2F%286sinh%28n+pi%29%29&random=false,

$B(n)=\int_k^{k+1}-\dfrac{y(y^2+1)\sin n\pi y}{6\sinh n\pi}dy$

$=\dfrac{(-1)^{n(k+1)}(k+1)(n^2\pi^2((k+1)^2+1)-6)-(-1)^{nk}k(n^2\pi^2(k^2+1)-6)}{6n^3\pi^3\sinh n\pi}$ , $\forall n,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ , $y\in(k,k+1)$

$\therefore H(x,y)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n(k+1)}(k+1)(n^2\pi^2((k+1)^2+1)-6)-(-1)^{nk}k(n^2\pi^2(k^2+1)-6)}{6n^3\pi^3\sinh n\pi}\prod_{k,k+1}(y)\sinh n\pi x\sin n\pi y$

$+\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n(k+1)}(k+1)(n^2\pi^2((k+1)^2-11)-6)-(-1)^{nk}k(n^2\pi^2(k^2-11)-6)}{6n^3\pi^3\sinh n\pi}\prod_{k,k+1}(x)\sin n\pi x\sinh n\pi y+\dfrac{xy(x^2+y^2)}{12} , x,y\in\mathbb R$